# Enable bootloader screen for Lenovo Vibe Z

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, bootloader, fastboot, bootloader-lock

I pressed and held volume up key for sometime and my Lenovo Vibe Z is seems to be bricked (not charging or switching on). I would like to get into to the boot-loader screen to factory reset the device. 
Two things:

1. Please help me with the key combinations required to get into boot-loader.
2. Or ways to unlock the boot-loader in Lenovo Vibe Z.

Comment: Volume up and Power key?

Comment: not happening..I don't understand..it should charge at-least..

Comment: How did you manage to brick it? Or is it simply not charging?

Comment: While I was on call I pressed and held volume up button..and that was it. Its bricked or not I have no clue.

Comment: Hold Volume Down and then hold Power

Comment: I would be more concerned with 'not charging' than anything else. Is the cable or the plug damaged? It may be a hard brick, i.e. damaged hardawre. Start with the plug and cable for the charger, try another socket and your PC to charge. Then try another cable / charger. Failing that, try another battery if you can get a hold of one, and so on until we can isolate where the problem is.

Comment: Done. Problem was with the charger, was using Samsung charger.
But I still have no clue why it got off by holding volume up key and I am sure that charging was above 20%, it should have resurrected to life when I pressed power button.
And while I am at it, this phone awesome except its antenna. Voice breaks with the jerks on road.